# import latex longtable into lyx with format changing

Tags: formatting, lyx, longtable, import

I apologize if my question was asked alot previously
i am generating my tables from stata into latex
then i try to import those tables (longtables) inside a table float in lyx
the result is a mess because of the format
i would like to widen the margins of the float so that all columns appear
i would like to add the longtable option which seems disabled in a float in order to see the rest of the table in the next page

I also would like to define the placement as here definitely without any page breaks

Can anyone help me with this
thank you in advance
Tania

Comment: Please use full stops as the question is not readable. It would also help if you provided a minimal example of Stata LaTeX table taht you're trying to import into LyX.

Comment: Yes, there can be no page breaks within a table float, but if you're using a `longtable` then you shouldn't use it anyway, so just don't. Rather than changing margins, you'd likely want to modify the table, e.g. by using `p` columns to limit the width of the column and enabling line breaks. However, it would be best if you added an example of such a table.